# what kind of type should I use in java to call this C function with JNI?

Tags: android, pointers, struct, java-native-interface, malloc

I get this problem when I wanna call a native `C` function in java on android use `JNI`. I pass a pointer to structure as a parameter in that `C` function, and allocate memory to that pointer.

So please tell me how can I call this `C` function in java? I googled for a long time but get no rewards.

Codes like this, A is the name of structure :

```
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL
Java_pkgname_NativeTools_create(JNIEnv *env, jclass jclazz, A **ptr) {
    *ptr = (A*) malloc(sizeof(A));
    if (*ptr != NULL ) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

and I don't know how to write the native interface :

```
public class NativeTools{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("LibName");
    }

    // TODO don't know what type in JNI should I use to declare this native function?
    public static native int create(?);
}
```

thanks a lot and sorry for my poor english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like this. You can use only [JNI datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html) as C function parameters. Anyway, there is nothing like *structs* or even *pointers* in Java. What was it, that you wanted to create on Java side and then "pass it to C" ? The nearest to *pointer* you could get is a reference type `jobject`, but C doesn't understand it as simply as you tried. It's a reference to *JVM object*, not *C struct*. It's only meant as a parameter to further JNI calls (which calls back to JVM).

There are tools which could help you improving the datatype interoperability (SWIG,JNA), but given the apparent fundamental misunderstanding, you should start with some basic reading:

```
http://192.9.162.55/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html
```

(can't do a proper link, SO forbids IP addresses)

Comment: I see. well, I'll try another way to solve this problem, maybe allocate memory in java and pass it to native code for more process?(sorry that I'm living in China, so I'll have a rest later, thanks a lot and I'll try it tomorrow:)   )

Comment: The only meaningful usage of memory allocated in Java and "passing to native code" is [memory-mapped ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). It depends on what "more process" you want to achieve.

Comment: if I write all code in C for example, things will like this: first I create a NULL pointer in 'main' function, and pass it to "create" function in order to allocate some memory to the ptr. then I pass that ptr to another "process" functions to do some extra work. and finally I pass the ptr to the "free/release" function to free the allocated memory. That's what I always do in pure C programming, but now I have to move this into android, with same "create","process" and "free/release" functions.I think java side just like the 'main' function, but it's not, can u give me a tutorial, thanks :)

Comment: You should understand that *there is no free/release in Java*. JVM does it for you. Also there are *no pointers in Java*. Actually everything is a pointer in Java (except primitives), but it's hidden from you. Java cannot be meaningfuly compared to C. Definitely not in space of S.O. comment. Please go learn basics before trying to play with JNI.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me:)  Maybe I'm not explain myself clearly, anyway, I'll solve this problem and give a feedback here.

Comment: Hi, I solved it by learning "Oracle JNI Doc. - Leveraging Existing Native Libraries".I've just read 4 chapters before:( . I wraped the native code, allocate dinamic memory and pass the address of it to java code with jint. So I can use these native memories for another C process by passing it back from java to C functions like C-Free etc. Thanks for all your advises! :)